# How to embed bootstrap code into PHP tags

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap-4

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM testtable");

echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='card' style='width: 18rem;'>";
        echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='' alt='Card image cap'>";
        echo "<div class='card-body'>";
            echo "<h5 class='card-title'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</h5>";
            echo "<p class='card-text'>" . $row['lastname'] . "</p>";
            echo "<a href='' class='btn btn-primary'>Go somewhere</a>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is a part of the code in homepage.php which also contains HTML code and uses Bootstrap. When the webpage is opened through XAMPP everything works correct (including the table which takes data from a table), but the Bootstrap card doesnt work.

Comment: Have you included required css, js files?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "doesn't work" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that "doesn't work", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: IMO it would be preferable to keep php from html separate so the code becomes more readable

Comment: Yeah Pal, it connect to a CDN. BTW all other parts of the same website works. I even added a bootstrap card after the PHP tags, and the HTML rendered it too

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say maybe the HTML for the cards is not being rendered at all (you can check the View Source feature in your browser to be sure)? If so that's probably because you've got two `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` loops consecutively. Of course, the second one won't run because you already fetched all the rows in the first loop, and it doesn't reset. A better approach would be to put all the query data into an array first, and then you can loop over the array as many times as you like.

Comment: Well I think some people are misunderstanding. I expected two things in HTML, one is a table which fetches data from the database and shows it on a table. Another is a Bootstrap card with the same data from the table. What i got is only the first <table> with the expected data, not the bootstrap card. @ADyson

Comment: Ok @ADyson trying your suggested edit now

Comment: Hey @ADyson just edited the code (Removed the second "while($row..")). Now I get the error "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null" (The card is being rendered)

Comment: If you literally just removed the `while` line then obviously you'll get an error because $row won't exist any more. That isn't what I suggested doing.

Comment: Ok @ADyson I just fixed it but come on man I didn't literally remove the "while" line, just removed the extra stuff. BTW thanks for suggesting to put values in an array and do the thing. Thanks man Its solved now

Comment: Well ok but that's what you said you did. And the error you got made it sound like you did that. We can only go off what you tell us, if you don't show the code or anything :-). Anyway glad you fixed it, I added as an answer in full below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML for the cards is almost certainly not being rendered at all (you can check the View Source feature in your browser to be sure).

That's because you've got two `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` loops consecutively. The second one won't run because you already fetched all the rows in the first loop, and it doesn't reset - the first loop runs until `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns false. After that, it will always return false for that query result, no matter if you start a new loop or not.

A better approach would be to put all the query data into an array first, and then you can loop over the array as many times as you like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM testtable");
$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $rows[] = $row;
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  echo "<div class='card' style='width: 18rem;'>";
  echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='' alt='Card image cap'>";
  echo "<div class='card-body'>";
  echo "<h5 class='card-title'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</h5>";
  echo "<p class='card-text'>" . $row['lastname'] . "</p>";
  echo "<a href='' class='btn btn-primary'>Go somewhere</a>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
}
```